# Jmeter jmx scripts when executed via maven keeps in running in a loop

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

When i try to run the jmx (find attached) in jmeter - it runs for one thread but the same jmx when run via maven with jmeter-maven-plugin keeps running in a loop. I have not used any method for now and just relying on static thread count and other numbers hardcoded in jmx.

[image]

POMs main component looks like this :
[image]

Folder structure looks like this: [image]

Command used : mvn clean verify

Jmeter version: 5.6.2
maven version: 3.9.1
jmeter-maven-plugin: 3.8.0

When running the same jmx via maven it keeps running in a loop:

[image]

On Jmeter GUI it runs normally for one user :
[image]
I am expecting it to work with the same number of threads from maven command line as mentioned in the jmx file.

Also i further plan to use methods to get users/loop count/ ramp up using methods example:  ${__P(users,1)} - so expecting to pass users from command line here.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue, check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) under target/jmeter/logs directory, it should contain the information regarding which test plan is being executed with how many threads.

[image]

Once you sort out "loop" execution problem you can parameterize the number of threads in the following way:

1. Define a [Maven property](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html) for the number of users:

   ```
   <properties>
       <threads>${users}</threads>
   </properties>
   ```
2. Add the above property to [JMeter User Properties](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties#adding-additional-properties-to-propertiesuser)

   ```
   <configuration>
       <propertiesUser>
           <threads>${threads}</threads>
       </propertiesUser>
   </configuration>
   ```
3. You should be able to override the number of users from the [Maven command line](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/apache-maven-cookbook/9781785286124/ch03s05.html) like:

   ```
   mvn -Dusers=100 clean verify
   ```

More information: [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)